# Conditional Counting with group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

Need help on conditional counting i can't display the data that i need to my report. i am using sql server 2008, sap crystal report

My Code

```
    SELECT c.Clients_Name
    ,COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN b.FI_result = 'Passed'
                AND Date_applied >= @DS
                AND Date_applied <= @DE
                THEN 1
            END) AS [Jan]
    ,COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN b.FI_result = 'Passed'
                AND Date_applied >= @DS
                AND Date_applied <= @DE
                THEN 1
            END) AS [Feb]
    ,COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN b.FI_result = 'Passed'
                AND Date_applied >= @DS
                AND Date_applied <= @DE
                THEN 1
            END) AS [Mar]
FROM Applicant_Operators AS a
INNER JOIN Applicant_IS_History AS b ON a.Applicant_ID = b.Applicant_ID
INNER JOIN Clients AS c ON b.Client_Name = c.Client_ID
WHERE Date_applied >= @DS
    AND Date_applied <= @DE
GROUP BY c.Clients_Name
```

`
Code display

```
Clients     Jan Feb Mar
DENSO       14  14  14
NPI         7   7   7
MICROTOP    48  48  48
```

what i want to display

```
Clients     Jan Feb Mar
DENSO       5   3   6
NPI         2   1   4
MICROTOP    10  20  18
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something to identify the month.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
SELECT c.Clients_Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.FI_result = 'Passed' AND
                     Date_applied >= @DS AND Date_applied <= @DE AND
                     MONTH(Date_applied) = 1
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS [Jan],
       . . .
```

I replaced the `count()` with a `sum()` just my personal preference for conditional aggregation.

Comment: Hi @gordonlinoff thank you so much your code help me solve my problem